# Keycloak returns 401 Unauthorized on accessing JAX-RS API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jax-rs, keycloak

I have a RESTful API service built using JAX-RS, and it's secured with Keycloak. I can't seem to be able to access the API endpoints since Keycloak returns:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
    <body>Unauthorized</body>
</html>
```

The API service is configured as a client on Keycloak **21.0.2**, as follows:
[image: Client Configuration on Keycloak]

As you can see in the screenshot above, **Authorization** for the client is enabled. I have a `User Profile Resource` and the complete Authorization configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "allowRemoteResourceManagement": false,
  "policyEnforcementMode": "ENFORCING",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "User Profile Resource",
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "displayName": "User Profile Resource",
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "b0595333-f9be-432c-bd62-fe50c5f7ad4b",
      "uris": [
        "/api/user/fetch"
      ],
      "scopes": [
        {
          "name": "read"
        },
        {
          "name": "update"
        },
        {
          "name": "delete"
        },
        {
          "name": "create"
        }
      ],
      "icon_uri": ""
    }
  ],
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": "f103545a-de6a-4e50-aab4-101c54f92cb7",
      "name": "Broker Role Policy",
      "description": "A policy for enforcing the role of Broker users on the platform.",
      "type": "role",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "roles": "[{\"id\":\"role-broker-user\",\"required\":true}]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "7e176f7c-eb58-4d63-ab6b-3146749a28c7",
      "name": "Create User Permission",
      "description": "Permission to create user.",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"User Profile Resource\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"create\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Broker Role Policy\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "13e1461f-53c3-46a8-8b1c-3bf39466560d",
      "name": "Update User Permission",
      "description": "Permission to update user.",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"User Profile Resource\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"update\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Broker Role Policy\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "fdcb52bf-870f-4533-8689-35b7d6d889d8",
      "name": "Delete User Permission",
      "description": "Permission to delete user.",
      "type": "scope",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"User Profile Resource\"]",
        "scopes": "[\"delete\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Broker Role Policy\"]"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "efed8eba-2ce8-4b96-b446-a1ded75a042b",
      "name": "User Read Permission",
      "description": "Permission to read/fetch a User.",
      "type": "resource",
      "logic": "POSITIVE",
      "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
      "config": {
        "resources": "[\"User Profile Resource\"]",
        "applyPolicies": "[\"Broker Role Policy\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "scopes": [
    {
      "id": "4774c801-7626-4e38-a10f-2c3efdc145de",
      "name": "create",
      "iconUri": "",
      "displayName": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": "5df5df9a-2b59-47cd-9654-bc62a2f43000",
      "name": "read",
      "iconUri": "",
      "displayName": "Read"
    },
    {
      "id": "8a21bb56-f39a-464a-a377-82ff418a5231",
      "name": "update",
      "iconUri": "",
      "displayName": "Update"
    },
    {
      "id": "7e3fc449-27c3-4578-b94d-c8af14951eae",
      "name": "delete",
      "iconUri": "",
      "displayName": "Delete"
    }
  ],
  "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS"
}
```

In my JAX-RS application, I have the following end-point that needs to be protected:

- `/api/user/fetch`

My `keycloak.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "realm": "hello-world-authz",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "my-resource",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "MY-SECRET"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "enforcement-mode": "ENFORCING",
    "user-managed-access": {},
    "paths": [
      {
        "name": "User Profile Resource",
        "path": "/api/user/fetch",
        "methods": [
          {
            "method": "GET",
            "scopes": ["read"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I successfully get the Access Token of a user (`edward`) through the following end-point: HTTP://localhost:8180/realms/hello-world-authz/protocol/openid-connect/token

I then go ahead to use this access token in the `Authorization` header of the request to `/api/user/fetch`, and I get back a `401 Unauthorized`.
What could I be doing wrong?

***NB:*** I followed the documentation here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html and still couldn't get it right.